Sketching complex numbers on a complex plane

Solving Re(iz+2) < 0 led me to y > 2. Does this mean when sketching this point that this refers to every point above 2 on the y axis (or Im axis on the complex plane in this instance)?

How can I identify a sketching point for $\lvert Arg(iz)\rvert$ < $\frac{\pi}{3}$


I know I can use z=x+yi for question 2 and substitute, but I am unsure how to proceed from there on. Substituting for z would yield $\lvert Arg(-y+ix)\rvert$

Your answer to (1) is correct. For (2), think polar coordinates. (One question per post on this site, please.)

The only thing I can think of is is somehow using tan$\theta$ = $\frac{y}{x}$. I am lost on this.

Given $z$ you know where $iz$ is. When does the argument (that is, the angle with the real axis) satisfy the inequality? You should be drawing pictures for these kinds of questions.

Your answer to (1) is not correct. $z$ is not necessarily on this axis. It lies in an open half-plane.

Since Arg(i) would be an angle corresponding to $\frac{\pi}{2}$ and given our inequality, does this mean Arg(iz) would be between $\frac{\pi}{6}$ and $\frac{-\pi}{6}$?

Let $z=x+yi$. Then $iz+2=2-y+xi$.
$Re(2-y+xi)=2-y$ and so the solution to $Re(iz+2)<0$ is the solution to $2-y<2$
As Anne commented, this is the open half-plane $y>0$ which should probably be written $Im(z)>0$ since $x$ and $y$ were not defined in the question.
As for $|Arg(iz)|<\frac{\pi}{3}$, re-writing as $\frac{-\pi}{3}<Arg(iz)<\frac{\pi}{3}$ is a good start.
From there, remember that the transformation from $z$ to $iz$ is a rotation anti-clockwise by $\frac{\pi}{2}$ so to undo this, rotate clockwise by $\frac{\pi}{2}$.
$\frac{-\pi}{3}-\frac{\pi}{2}=\frac{-5\pi}{6}$ and $\frac{\pi}{3}-\frac{\pi}{2}=\frac{-\pi}{6}$.
When sketching, the boundaries should be dashed lines due to the type of inequality.
